# Is that necessary to install Git server if I want to have remote repository access over ssh?

Tags: git

Could you please explain, do I really need to install git server on the remote machine if I only need to place repository there and access it over ssh?

My ignorance probably starts from misunderstanding some key git operation principle so I would be glad if someone will explain it to me.

I thought that remote server for git is just a place where it stores files pretty much like local folder of my PC and I can have remote server with ssh access to host my repo on it without a need to install git server binaries there.

Is that possible? If not, could you explain me this thing I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the files required by git to run are stored locally to a checkout (in the `.git` directory).  You *could* just access your git repository over SSH and effectively treat it like a repository on your local machine, e.g by mounting the remote folder locally.

However, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that.  You can't do anything useful without the git binaries installed.  If you just wanted to use the repository for private versioning, then you might as well install and run in locally, and back it up with your usual backup methods.  If you want to use the repository to collaborate with others, then you need the git binaries available on a server that all your collaborators can access.

There is no meaningful distinction between a git "server" and a git "client".  It's a distributed versioning system, which means each checkout is a fully-functioning version repository in its own right.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that (in most cases) you do need **git** installed on the remote machine, even if you don't need any special server software

Comment: I'm going to use remote server just to synchronize my work across my three PCs for convenience. None except me will be using it. So, I think I can just make remote repository via SSH, right?

Comment: Do you really need git installed on the remote machine to push to it via ssh?

Comment: @static_rtti: Yes, essentially - you only need a very small set of commands (see [`git-shell(1)`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html), but it's much easier to just install `git` than to bother reducing down to that set. The upshot is that when you push via SSH, you're actually running Git commands on the remote.

Comment: "by mounting the remote folder locally" - I don't think that will work in all cases.  What if two users on different machines have mounted the same git repo from a third machine.  Will the file locking and presence of two possibly different versions of git really work?  In all cases?  Having git on the remote machine allows each user's git to run git commands on the remote machine (e.g., the same git, with the same filesystem).  This will guarantee file locking and access working properly.

Answer (score 4):

Sure it is possible to have an ssh access without a "git server".
You need a ssh server (daemon) though.

Don't mix a "remote server" and a "remote (or upstream actually) repo: a remote repo can be a simple directory right next to your current repo (local protocol).

**[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)** is a good illustration, using the forced command mechanism of ssh to manage **authorization** (not access).
See [Gitolite without SSH](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/0f377a7679845e1db9e6ea0830da7d25ba4ecf07/doc/gitolite-without-ssh.mkd) to realize that just a sshd is enough for git repo access.

See also [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html) for the various protocols supported by Git.

Answer (score 3):

If operating over SSH you don't need a git server.  The trick are getting the file permissions correct so that everyone can edit the files.

If you're doing this just for yourself, on the server:

```
 git init --bare
```

If you're doing it with other developers then you'll need to:

```
 mkdir repo
 chgrp GROUP repo
 chmod g+rwxs repo
 cd repo
 git init --bare --shared=group
```